# Search on field in Content Manager

Tags: 2011, core-service, search

I'm using the Core Service client in Tridion 2011SP to do a search for components with a certain schema.

I managed to filter out all components that have a certain value in a single line value field. Now I'm trying to filter out all components that have a date field set to a date before a given timestamp.

Does anyone know if this is even possible with the CM search? Because it's based on Solr, I thought I could do it with something like this:

```
searchQuery.BasedOnSchemas = new[] {
    new BasedOnSchemaData {
        Field = "PublicEmbargo",
        FieldValue = "[* TO 2013-8-20T09:55:00.000Z]",
        Schema = new LinkToSchemaData {
            IdRef = "tcm:10-123456-8",
            Title = "SomeSchemaWithDate"
        }
    }
};
```

However this doesn't seem to work and returns an error "maxClauseCount is set to 10240" from Solr.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have never had to do this, but I think that this can be done through the API.  The fact that you are getting this error is a good sign!

In Lucene (which Solr is based on) the maxClauseCount exceeded error is normally because the number of terms/unknowns in your query makes it very 'vague'.  I believe that the value can be  increased in configuration.  However, the best approach is normally to simplify the query.

Can you try this with a less specific date query (fewer decimal places)?  e.g.  `FieldValue = "[* TO 2013-08-20]"` or `FieldValue = "[1977-01-01 TO 2013-08-20]"`

There is a little more information on this error in Lucene [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/8093).

**Edit by Alvin**: Using the same format (`"[2011-01-01 TO 2012-01-01]"`) or even `"[2012 TO 2015]"` seems to work in advanced search as well. In the screenshot below, Components with a date field after 2012 are correctly filtered out (the `Modified` column is a separate date).

[image: Advanced Search on a date uses the same format]

Comment: Interesting that you choose 1977 to start the query with, probably even safe enough to use January 1, 2000 as there won't be much customers with content before that date.

Comment: Sweet! This seems to work. Both from the Core Service as well as from a Virtual Folder query.

Comment: @Bart - I'm just showing my age! :)

Comment: 1977 places you in the murky region between PC man and Unix man.

Comment: Yes, it's very murky water at times!  :)

Comment: I tested and added a CME advanced search example. I'd just be careful with the syntax because search seemed to accept impractical dates with typos (e.g. 20155 works but will pull back too much and 2015d-01-01 works but I'm not sure what it means).

Comment: Note I wasn't able to get `*` as a wild card to return the right range of items in advanced search. Starting with the asterisk as in `[* TO 2012-01-01]` returned all items, even with dates after 2012-01-01.