# How Could I search in Solr query inside a schema field a Date Type of CMS?

Tags: sdl-tridion, search, query, solr

There Are any way to search with a certain Field as an example:
http://blog.trivident.com/releasing-the-tiger-how-to-profit-from-solr-in-your-tridion-cm/

(RepositoryId:tcm:0-3-1 OR RepositoryId:tcm:0-5-1 OR RepositoryId:tcm:0-7-1 OR RepositoryId:tcm:0-109-1 OR RepositoryId:tcm:0-148-1) AND OrganizationalItemAncestorIds:tcm:*-4-2 AND (SchemaId:tcm:*-2525-8 AND **CatchAllXml:"headline Generation headline"**~1000000)

But in our case we try to search by a Date type in Tridion ex:

**CatchAllXml:"headline 2019-02-07T00:00:00.184 headline"**

We have tried too as Tridion view:

**CatchAllXml:"headline 2/7/2019 12:00 AM headline"**

But both are not working right in solr:

Do you know how we could put this date in order to solr find a component that inside of this field have this Date ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange. Can you please provide Tridion version you are currently  using.

Comment: SDL Web Content Manger - build 8.5.0 version

Comment: Can you check this link see if this helps - https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/612/search-on-field-in-content-manager

Comment: Thanks for your help ! with this issue I ve could solve our problem.

Comment: happy it helped

Comment: I have Another problem that I couldn't understand.
I have searched with this interval:
[2019-02-01 TO 2019-06-14] and the result is 17 components
but I've searched with one day more of interval:
[2019-02-01 TO 2019-06-15] And the result produce an ERROR:

Why is happening that result ? Any idea about it ?

Comment: Not sure if the date format is passed properly

Comment: ERROR TRACE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown query type "org.apache.lucene.search.TermRangeQuery" found in phrase query string "bookingStartDate [2019-02-01 TO 2019-06-15] bookingStartDate"
 at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.TridionComplexPhraseQueryParser$ComplexPhraseQuery.rewrite(TridionComplexPhraseQueryParser.java:419)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.rewrite(BooleanQuery.java:412)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.rewrite(BooleanQuery.java:412)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.rewrite(IndexSearcher.java:639)

Comment: It's working as we could espected when teh result is 17 but the second one only adding one day more is broken the query, it's strange

Comment: Anand NS, What is the correct format for this case ?

Answer (score 2):

please refer to the [Link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/612/search-on-field-in-content-manager)

for the solution to query based on the field.