# Tridion solr query

Tags: sdl-tridion, solr

Are there any documents or website about solr query something like http://blog.trivident.com/releasing-the-tiger-how-to-profit-from-solr-in-your-tridion-cm/ where we can view some real example about slor query?

Comment: refer to this link and the reference to other stack exchange link for more details query fro CM https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21121/how-could-i-search-in-solr-query-inside-a-schema-field-a-date-type-of-cms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to query from the solr admin Tridion CME (e.g. http://my.tridion:8983) (or) http://my.tridion:8983/#/tridion You will get a prompt for a username and password. The “MTSUser” (Tridion’s system user) and select the collection and click on query to see the results refer [link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/query-screen.html#query-screen)

Some Examples

All Results - [Link](http://localhost:8983/tridion/select?q=*%3A*&wt=xml&indent=true)

Only Title - [Link](http://localhost:8983/tridion/select?q=Title:Test&wt=xml&indent=true)

You can do the same for other fields ( SchemaId, ItemType) etc.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Note that you won’t find information about Solr queries in the SDL Tridion Docs, because we want to avoid people going wild with custom Solr queries in their implementation.

In the future, Solr may be replaced (with Elasticsearch) and we won’t be able to keep the low-level query language compatitble. If you only use Tridion’s `SearchQuery`, you should be fine, though.